# group policy: computer configuration applied, user configuration doesn't

Tags: configuration, active-directory, group-policy

I'm setting a group policy, but for some reason it's not applying

When i'm running gpresult I get the following result.
The "Auto-lock" policy which I want to have set is listed in here.

```
Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Intranet
    Printer
    Network Drives
    Auto-lock
    Default Domain Policy
```

When looking at following image, "User Configuration" Settings don't get applied.
As a test I also added a setting inside "Computer Configuration", this one does get applied, but doesn't have the desired effect.

[image]

Why are my "Computer Configurations" applied, but are the "User Configuration" Settings of the same policy left out?

Answer (score 0):

User policies have to be applied to users not computer objects.
Mixing user & computer policies in one gpo is nearly always wrong